# Process Bar for a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, progress-bar

I have a bash script to run a block of commands on multiple remote machine ($1 = remote ip list file) via ssh. I created a function (function1) with all commands and call on remote machine via ssh.
the script is working fine. I am trying to add a progress bar with %  on process (connecting remote machine one by one and do the work). I added the code but it not working

Complete script:-

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'AMM_Username: ' uservar
read -sp 'AMM_Password: ' passvar
## Commands
function function1() {
echo ""
echo -e "Hostname $(hostname)"
echo -e "Uptime $(uptime)" 
echo -e "Running Kernel $(uname -r)" 
echo -e "Date $(date)" 
echo -e "TimeZone $(basename $(ls -l /etc/localtime | grep -o '/usr/share/zoneinfo/.*'))" 
echo ""
}
## 
function run_remote_command() {
    # Show progress bar before command is executed
    echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
    sleep 1

while read -r server; do
        sshpass -p "$passvar" ssh -q -n "$uservar@$server" "$(typeset -f); function1"  > "output.txt"
    else
        echo "Server $server is not reachable."
    fi

done < "$1"

    # Show progress bar after command is executed
    echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
    echo -ne '\n'
}
run_remote_command
```

output I am getting

```
 + run_remote_command
 + echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
 + sleep 1                 (33%)
Lin_check.sh: line 510: : No such file or directory
 + echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
 + echo -ne '\n'########   (100%)
```

Line no 510 -> sshpass -p "$passvar" ssh -q -n "$uservar@$server" "$(typeset -f); function1"  > "output.txt"

But this line working with out process bar code (given below).

```
function run_remote_command() {
    # Show progress bar before command is executed
    echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
    sleep 1
    # Show progress bar after command is executed
    echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
    echo -ne '\n'
}
```

Please help me to fix or modify the code.

Thanks in advance,

vijay

Comment: `wc -l` on the file which you are failing to pass to run_remote_command as $1 would give you the number of lines it contains. You could print a # for each tenth of the file.

Comment: @EdMorton yes requesting help to implement progress bar.   I am trying to implement progress bar, "while code block" working fine with out progress bar code.

Comment: And `Lin_check.sh` exists on the remote machine and is called as part of `function1`? As is, your question is too broad. Reduce it down to a [mcve] and include your best attempt to solve the "progress bar" problem. Are you trying to provide a wrapper that will work on any script/function/etc OR do you want a function you can include inside of any shell script code? Please don't reply in comments, but update your question so readers can help you with a focused problem and fixing your code. (@stark 's idea sounds good enough, depending  on your needs). Good luck.

Comment: the 1st function is syntactically invalid but since we don't have a complete (minimal) reproducible example it's hard to tell if this is leading to your error or masked by the current error; consider cutting-n-pasting your code (along with appropriate shebang) at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for help in diagnosing syntax issues

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ["while code block" working fine with out progress bar code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747690/process-bar-for-a-bash-script/76749836#comment135305818_76747690) - It's impossible for the function in your question, called as you show in your question, to run correctly since the `while read` loop is reading from `$1` but you call the function without an argument.

```
$ foo() { while read line; do echo "$line"; done < "$1"; }
$ foo
-bash: : No such file or directory
```

Ask a new question containing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you further if you need more than that.